# dominated convergence theorem on the heat kernel

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $f \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $K_t = (4\pi t)^{-\frac{d}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}} $ for every $t>0$.

I want to prove this :

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}(K_t*f)(x)&=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} K_t(x-y) f(y)dy = \lim_{h \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  \frac{K_{t+h}-K_t}{h}(x-y)f(y) dy\\
&=  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}   \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{K_{t+h}-K_t}{h}(x-y)f(y) dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Delta K_t(x-y)f(y)dy=((\Delta K_t)*f)(x)
\end{align*}

In order to prove the third equality, I thought I could use the dominated convegrence theorem since $||\Delta K_t * f||_1$$ \leq ||{\Delta K_t}||_1 ||{f}||_1< \infty.$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} K_t(x-y)  f(y) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{K_{t+h}-K_t}{h}(x-y)f(y) = \Delta K_t(x-y)f(y) .$$
Now, by definition of the limit, for every $\epsilon > 0 $, there exists $\delta>0 $ such that for every $h\leq \delta$,
$$\left| \frac{K_{t+h}-K_t}{h}(x-y)f(y) \right| \leq \Delta K_t(x-y)f(y) + \epsilon$$
taking $\epsilon = \Delta K_t(x-y)f(y)$, there exists $T$ such that for every $h \leq T$
$$\left| \frac{K_{t+h}-K_t}{h}(x-y)f(y) \right| \leq 2\Delta K_t(x-y)f(y) .$$

clearly I have a dependance of T to y which mean I can't use this, I can't find a better bound, does someone have a good idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wlog let $d=1$. The heat kernel satisfies the heat equation, so $\partial_tK_t(x)=\Delta K_t(x)$. Therefore $(\partial_tK_t*f)(x)=(\Delta K_t*f)(x)$. We indicate the Fourier transform with $\hat{g}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)e^{-i\xi x}dx$. We have that $(\widehat{\Delta K_t*f})(\xi)=(-\xi^2\hat{K}_t(\xi))\hat{f}(\xi)=\hat{K}_t(\xi)(-\xi^2\hat{f}(\xi))=(\widehat{K_t*\Delta f})(\xi)$. This implies $(\Delta K_t*f)(x)=(K_t*\Delta f)(x)$ a.e. Now note that
$$(K_t*\Delta f)(x)=E^x[\Delta f(\sqrt{2}W_t)]$$
where $W=(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion and $E^x[.]$ the expectation wrt the law of the process started at $x$ i.e. $E^x[f(\sqrt{2}W_t)]=E[f(x+\sqrt{2}W_t)]$. Dynkin's formula yields $E^x[\Delta f(\sqrt{2}W_t)]=\partial_tE^x[f(\sqrt{2}W_t)]$. Finally note that $(K_t*f)(x)=E^x[f(\sqrt{2}W_t)]$. In summary, the following holds for a.a. $x$:
$$\begin{aligned}&(\partial_tK_t*f)(x)=(\Delta K_t*f)(x)=(K_t*\Delta f)(x)=\\
&=E^x[\Delta f(\sqrt{2}W_t)]=\partial_tE^x[f(\sqrt{2}W_t)]=\partial_t(K_t*f)(x)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Hey Snoop, thank you for your answer, I am not really familiar with Dynkin's formula (and Brownian motion in general). It will take me some times to check your answer (even if it seems true first hand). Thank you again :)

Comment: @G__C You're welcome. Do let me know if you want me to provide more details. [Dynkin's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin%27s_formula) works for a general Ito diffusion described by an SDE, but in this case we just have $dX_t=0\cdot dt + \sqrt{2}\cdot dW_t$ so $b=0,\sigma=\sqrt{2}$ constant.